# Disable middleware for one action

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I've created a middleware (IMiddleware implementation) that checks some header. It works fine but I need to disable it for one action. I know I can parse url but is there any other way? I tried to mark an action by attribute but this data is unavailable in middleware.

Comment: At that low level you are left with parsing the URL.

Comment: So I should use IActionFilter? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Conditional middleware based on request in ASP.NET Core

this is how you can implement

```
app.UseMiddlewareOne();

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddlewareTwo();
});

app.UseMiddlewareThree();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but "I know I can parse url but is there any other way?"

Comment: @Serg046 have to wait for others :D